# Unable To See Changes To A Record

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

Ok I need some advice on what to do next to solve this issue. Over a week ago I changed the A records for my domain to point to my new vps. Now a week later no matter what I try I cannot see the domain on my home PCs, I can however see it when I use my mobile "using 4G".

So far I have tried the following:

1. Cleared the cache on all my machines within the house.
2. I have reset the router.
3. I have checked to make sure the A records are pointing to the correct place and according to a 3rd party site they all now point to the new server.
4. I have had my family in a separate location try and they also get the old domain.

I am a little unsure what to do next, I am wondering if it is related to our Internet provider as both myself and my family use the same (Sky in the UK). As mentioned the domain loads fine when it is loaded via my mobile.

Thanks

Comment: Without the domain name we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, dev.sashhairandbeauty.co.uk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [ran your domain through Zonemaster](https://zonemaster.iis.se/?resultid=d9258b2493f29db0), and it showed an issue:

> All nameservers in the delegation are in the same AS (8560).

This means that if your internet provider has a problem with routing packets to that AS, you're not going to be able to connect to any of your nameservers. This can explain why you're getting the right result on your mobile but not on two separate computers connected to the same internet provider.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any host entries for the domain added in your PCs.

For linux, check the file /etc/hosts.

For windows, C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

If there are no entries for your domain in this file, then we can narrow it down to your ISP. You can then get in touch with their support team for getting this resolved.

*PS: If you have WiFi on any of these PCs, you can turn on your mobile hotspot, connect the PC to it and see if the issue persists, just to make extra sure.*

Comment: Ok just connected to the domain through the hotspot on my mobile and it seems to be ok. Would this indicate an issue with an external network and not the one within the house?